# Probability density function given by $f(x) = (3/16) (4 − x ^2 )$, for $0≤X≤ 2$. Find $E(X^3)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

The question asks for the answer to be in 2 decimals. It also does not specify whether the random variable $X$ is continuous or discrete, however I'm assuming it's continuous due to the function itself being a curve when plotting it on the calculator (is this a correct form of reasoning?).

Then the expected value $E(X^3)=\int x^3f(x)dx = \int x^3 (3/16) (4 − x ^2 )dx$,  with the limits from $0$ to $2$.

This I derived to be,
$(3/16)[X^4] - (3/16)[X^6/6]$, and with the limits this is equal to $1$.

Now, this is obviously not in the required form of a decimal-number. So I tried thinking of the function as a discrete random variable instead and got,

$E(X^3)=\sum x^3f(x)=\sum x^3(3/16)(4-x^2)$, considering the possible values as $X=\{0, 1, 2\}$, I got the expected value to be equal to $9/16=0.5625≈0.56$ which is in the form of two decimals the question was looking for.

Have I done a miscalculation or was I in fact supposed to use the discrete method for this? If so, how can I know in the future which one to choose from (discrete/continuous), just by looking at the function?

Thanks.

Comment: If $f$ was the pmf of a discrete random variable, then what would $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)$ be?

Comment: @Lythia I'd say $1$. I'd love to hear an expansion of your thought-process.

Comment: Except that the sum would not be $1$ (@Lythia's point) hence we are obviously in the continuous case. Ans.: $$1.00$$

Comment: But how can we know the function to be continuous? I get that my first way of solving it would yield $1.00$, but how can I be sure it's not the other alternative (0.56)? And thanks for commenting.

Comment: This has been pointed at, 47 mins ago, and explained 39 mins ago... Were you distracted by other activities at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrete random variables can be derived from functions that look as if they should be continuous so look at the values that the random variable can take.

The random variable is continuous since the author specifies that $X$ can take any value in the closed interval [0,2].

Needless to say it is remiss of the author not to be more clear.

Comment: So the answer then is $1.00$? and thanks for commenting!

Comment: Yes, the answer shoud be 1.00. Also, as suggested, the point of checking  P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2) is to see if this is 1. If this is not 1 then you don't have a valid PDF. For that matter, you could check that $\int\limits_0^2 {f(x) = 1} $.

Comment: @Newman :It is customary to accept useful answers on this website. That way the question is closed Also, folk do spend their time answering so it is only polite. Can you do this? Thank you.